# R ggplot geom_smooth(method=lm) add correlation in plot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I had a dataframe like this:

```
 d <- data.frame("accuracy" = c(0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,.65,.78,.86,.95), 
            "size" = c(10,15,25,30,35,5,9,12),
            "classes" = c("1vs2","1vs2","1vs2","1vs2","2vs3","2vs3","2vs3","2vs3"),
            "significance"=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2"),
            "percentage"=c(0.05,0.3,0.08,0.07,0.2,0.34,0.65,0.8))
```

and I would like to create a plot like this with the followed command:

```
 ggplot(data=d,aes(x=accuracy,y=size,color=classes)) + geom_point(aes(shape=significance,size=percentage)) + geom_smooth(method=lm,se=T,fullrange=F,aes(fill=classes))
```

this is the result at the moment:

[image]

but I would like to add the correlation of linear model for each "classes" type in the legend.
How can I add this information? 
So in the legend I want to have
correlation
1vs2 = 0.5
2vs3 = 0.3

Comment: Here is a manual solution that might help get you started: `+ scale_color_discrete(name="correlation", labels=c("1vs2 = 0.5", "2vs3 = 0.3")) + guides(fill=FALSE)`